# ruby on rails can't connect to postgres got PG::Error: fe_sendauth: no password supplie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, canvas

I'm trying to run a local canvas instance on my mac(os 10.9.4) following this guide:
https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start

Before I fired up the canvas server I needed to populate the database, then I ran:

```
bundle exec rake db:initial_setup
```

But then I got this error:

```
rake aborted!
PG::Error: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/Users/calvinmwhu/gems/bundler/gems/rails-e86daf8ff727/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:941:in `initialize'
/Users/calvinmwhu/gems/bundler/gems/rails-e86daf8ff727/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:941:in `new'
/Users/calvinmwhu/gems/bundler/gems/rails-e86daf8ff727/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:941:in `connect'
/Users/calvinmwhu/gems/bundler/gems/rails-e86daf8ff727/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:217:in `initialize'
```

I'm running ruby 1.9.3p547, and my database.yml looks like:

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: canvas_test
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  timeout: 5000

test-in-memory:
 adapter: sqlite3
 encoding: utf8
 database: ':memory:'
 pool: 1

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: canvas_development
  timeout: 5000
queue:
   adapter: postgresql
   encoding: utf8
   database: canvas_queue_development
   timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: canvas_production
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: 
  timeout: 5000
queue:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: canvas_queue_production
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: 
  timeout: 5000
```

And my pg_hba.conf is:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32           trust 
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                trust 
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                md5
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32           trust 
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

And finally here is a list of all the databases I have created in postgres:

```
           Name           |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
--------------------------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 canvas_development       | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 canvas_queue_development | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 postgres                 | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 template0                | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
                          |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1                | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
                          |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)
```

Sorry for asking this I know some similar questions have been asked before. But I tried almost all posted solutions and none of them worked. Any idea about this ? It forces me to provide a password but should I type that in database.yml (I already did this but didn't work)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with pg_hba and postgres user. 
You are using MacOS, so on your local machine under the test and development sections of the database.yml file you should change the username to your logged in username (not postgres).